# JavaScript on mouseDown get parentElement when child is clicked

Tags: javascript

In the following scenario, there's a `mouseDown` event listener on `<div class="main" id="main">`

If any of the elements were clicked, how can I get to the `<div class="subChild" role="menuitem" id="x">` parent of that element?

For eg:
If `This is Element 5` is clicked the node I'm trying to get is `<div class="subChild" role="menuitem" id="3">`

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxkezo7a/3/)

```
<div class="main" id="main">
    <div class="mainChild">
        <div class="subChild" role="menuitem" id="1">
            <div class="sub">
                <div class="kidOne">This is Element 1</div>
                <div class="kidTwo">This is Element 2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="subChild" role="menuitem" id="2">
            <div class="sub">
                <div class="kidOne">This is Element 3</div>
                <div class="kidTwo">This is Element 4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="subChild" role="menuitem" id="3">
            <div class="sub">
                <div class="kidOne">This is Element 5</div>
                <div class="kidTwo">This is Element 6</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
k = document.getElementById('main');

k.addEventListener('mousedown', myFunction)

function myFunction(event) {
    console.log(event.target)
    console.log(this);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use Element.closest() to get parent  elements like that

```
k = document.getElementById('main');

k.addEventListener('mousedown', myFunction)

function myFunction(event) {
    console.log(event.target)
    console.log(event.target.closest('.subChild'));

}
```

More information Click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily go up from a node to its parent using `.parentElement` or `.parentNode`.

So, by chaining that twice on the `event.target.parentElement.parentElement`, you have your subChild element!

```js
k = document.getElementById('main');

k.addEventListener('mousedown', myFunction)

function myFunction(event) {
    console.log(event.target.parentElement.parentElement);
}
```

```html
<div class="main" id="main">
    <div class="mainChild">
        <div class="subChild" role="menuitem" id="1">
            <div class="sub">
                <div class="kidOne">This is Element 1</div>
                <div class="kidTwo">This is Element 2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="subChild" role="menuitem" id="2">
            <div class="sub">
                <div class="kidOne">This is Element 3</div>
                <div class="kidTwo">This is Element 4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="subChild" role="menuitem" id="3">
            <div class="sub">
                <div class="kidOne">This is Element 5</div>
                <div class="kidTwo">This is Element 6</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```